# Getting VBA to Reference and Accept 2 Word Source Code (HTML)

Tags: html, vba, excel, rename

I'd like to have someone fill out specific cells in a spread sheet, and have those cells be uploaded to a webpage when the macro is run. Now, I've taken the code from this webpage:

http://www.familycomputerclub.com/how-to-login-automatically-into-website-using-excel-vba.html

and have altered it to do what I want. It works for the source code that only has a one word name, though:

```
<td align=right class=lbl>Model </td>
    <td align=left><input type=text size=20 name="xModel" value=""></td>
  </tr>
```

It does not work for source code that has a two letter name:

```
    <td align=right class=lbl>Serial Number </td>
    <td align=left><input type=text size=20 name="xSerial Number" value=""></td>
  </tr>
```

The code I have is as follows:

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer
Sub MyTruck()
 Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
 Dim MyURL As String
On Error GoTo Err_Clear
 MyURL = "http://website.com"
Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
 MyBrowser.Silent = True
 MyBrowser.navigate MyURL
 MyBrowser.Visible = True

Do
Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document
HTMLDoc.all.Name.Value = "John Miller" 'Enter your name here
HTMLDoc.all.Email.Value = "John.Miller@gmail.com" 'Enter your email here
HTMLDoc.all.xDepartment.Value = "WHSE" 'Enter Department Here
HTMLDoc.all.XPhone Number.Value = "6035554895" 'Enter Phone Number Here
HTMLDoc.all.xEquipment Number.Value = "544" 'Enter Equipment Number Here
HTMLDoc.all.xModel.Value = "CAT" 'Enter Model Here
HTMLDoc.all.xSerial Number.Value = "M711894xvJq" 'Enter Serial Number Here

For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
If MyHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next
Err_Clear:
 If Err <> 0 Then
 Err.Clear
 Resume Next
 End If
End Sub
```

In this shortened version of the code(I eliminated some of the HTMLDoc.All code because I was trying to save space), everything works except for the phone number, equipment number, and serial number. If there is anyway to make this work with two word source codes, that would be appreciated. I've tried using "", underscores, and taking out spaces completely. I tried to dim the name to something with spaces, but I'm  not sure that I did it right. Thanks in advance!!!

I also can't alter the source code, the website is a corporate website.

Comment: `HTMLDoc.all("abc def")` does this work

Comment: THANK YOU!! That works!'

Comment: or `HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("xSerial Number")(0)` if you're using IE9 or above.